# PHP error help on while loop

Tags: php, blogs, fatal-error

I can't figure out how to resolve a PHP error.

On the code below I receive the error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getintro() (previously declared ... on line 94)

I marked line 94 below. Any help or guidance is appreciated. My goal is to loop out each blog post based on each row of the database with only a portion of the text showing. When the link it clicked, it should open the full blog with comments in blog.php

```
    <?php   // retreive post
     include('php/config.php');
    include ('php/function.php');
    dbConnect();

    $blog_query = mysql_query(
    'SELECT * 
    FROM Blog
    ORDER BY DATE DESC');

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($blog_query)):

    $date = date_create($row['DATE']);
    $str = $row['CONTENT'];
    $ID = $row['ID'];

LINE 94    function getIntro($str, $count = 200) {
        return preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr(nl2br($str), 0, $count)) . "   <a href=\"blog.php?page={$ID}\" class=\"changeColor\">Read more...</a>\n";
        }
        $new_string = getIntro($str);
    ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2><?php echo $row['TITLE']?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo date_format($date, 'l, F j, Y')?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $new_string?></p>
    </div>

</div>      
<?php endwhile?>
```

Comment: Your declaring a function in a while loop? So if it is at the second iteration it's trying to overwrite the function which doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is being declared inside the loop. Move the function declaration outside of the loop.

```
    <?php   // retreive post
     include('php/config.php');
    include ('php/function.php');
    dbConnect();

    $blog_query = mysql_query(
    'SELECT * 
    FROM Blog
    ORDER BY DATE DESC');

    function getIntro($str, $count = 200) {
        return preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr(nl2br($str), 0, $count)) . "   <a href=\"blog.php?page={$ID}\" class=\"changeColor\">Read more...</a>\n";
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($blog_query)):

    $date = date_create($row['DATE']);
    $str = $row['CONTENT'];
    $ID = $row['ID'];

    $new_string = getIntro($str);
    ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2><?php echo $row['TITLE']?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo date_format($date, 'l, F j, Y')?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $new_string?></p>
    </div>

</div>      
<?php endwhile?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a function in a loop, so every iteration it re-declares the same function which is causing the issue. I would declare the function above the loop and call the function inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take your function declaration out the while loop! (The declaration has to be before your using it!)

```
function getIntro($str, $count = 200) {
        return preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr(nl2br($str), 0, $count)) . "   <a href=\"blog.php?page={$ID}\" class=\"changeColor\">Read more...</a>\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the function definition out of the loop, e.g. place it before dbConnect:

```
function getIntro($str, $count = 200) {
        return preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr(nl2br($str), 0, $count)) . "   <a href=\"blog.php?page={$ID}\" class=\"changeColor\">Read more...</a>\n";
        }
```